# Wait until any task completed

Tags: c++, multithreading, task, mutex, condition-variable

I am trying to write a simple `task` class. It is a wrapper around  `std::future`, it holds its state (`not_started`, `running`, `completed`), can start processing of given job on demand and it can repeatedly return result of its processing.

I can also offer some global functions for work with these tasks. But I am a little bit stuck in writing `size_t wait_any(std::vector<task<T>>& tasks)` function. This function is given a vector of tasks and should return index of the first completed task. If there are more tasks completed at the beginning, one of them must be returned (but this is not the problem).

A simple implementation using active waiting is following:

```
template <typename T>
size_t wait_any(std::vector<task<T>>& tasks) {

    if (tasks.size() == 0) throw std::exception("Waiting for empty vector of tasks!");

    for (auto i = tasks.begin(); i != tasks.end(); ++i) {
        (*i).try_start();
    }

    while (true) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != tasks.size(); ++i) {
            if (tasks[i].is_completed()) return i;
        }
    }
}
```

**I would appreciate passive waiting for any completition.** A `std::this_thread::yield` function is available, but I would rather not use it.  As mentioned in documentation:

> The exact behavior of this function depends on the implementation, in particular on the mechanics of the OS scheduler in use and the state of the system.

It seems that I should use `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex` to get the whole thing working. There are a lot of examples showing use of these things, but I do not understand it at all and I have not found solution for this particular problem.

I would guess that I should create a `std::condition_variable` (just `cv` further) in the `wait_any` function. Then this `cv` (pointer) should be registered to all tasks from given vector. Once any of the tasks is completed (I can handle the moment when a task is done) it should call `std::condition_variable::notify_one` for all `cv`'s registered in this task. These notified `cv`'s should be also removed from all tasks which are holding them.

Now, I do not know how to use `mutex`es. I probably need to prevent multiple calls of notification and many other problems.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This example could help: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/699/threading/13552/using-condition-variables#t=201705061205000751576

Comment: You can't spin waiting for a task to complete because you are using all of the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that since you only need one notification, you can use `std::call_once` to set the task_id which you require.

A naive way to go about it would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

    std::once_flag lala;
    std::atomic_int winner( -1 );

    void silly_task( int task_id )
    {
        //do nothing
        std::call_once ( lala, [&]()
        {
            std::cout << "thread " << task_id << " wins" << std::endl;
            winner = task_id;
        } );
    }

    int main(){

        std::vector<std::thread> vt;
        for ( int i=0;  i < 10 ; i ++ )
        {
            vt.push_back( std::thread( &silly_task, i) );

        }

        while ( winner == -1 )
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
        for ( int i=0;  i < 10 ; i ++ )
        {
            vt[i].join();

        }

        return 0;
    } // end main
```